# Conditionally set proxy_cache_use_stale parameters in Nginx

Tags: nginx, caching, openresty

I need to active/inactive '**updating**' params of **proxy_cache_use_stale** directive based on a cookie value in Nginx.

This is the normal config

```
 proxy_cache_use_stale error updating timeout http_500;
```

I change the config to the following:

```
if ($cookie_req = 1){
    proxy_cache_use_stale error updating timeout http_500;
}
if ($cookie_req = 2){
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500;
}
```

When I validate the new config through **nginx -t** the following error raised.

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_cache_use_stale" directive is not allowed ...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I used access_by_lua_block

```
location @no_updating {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error updating timeout http_500;
}

location @default {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500;
}

location / {
    access_by_lua_block {
        local no_updating = ngx.var.cookie_req
        if no_updating == "2" then
            ngx.exec("@no_updating")
        else
            ngx.exec("@default")
        end
    }
}
```